# how to handle error in flutter charts when it doesn't find

Tags: flutter, dart

i have some charts in my application when repose hits with statuscode 200  i'm getting the response

```
{"current_Year":{"grocery":36.69,"oac":0.0,"abc":48.04,"baby_care":0.0,"utensils":3.67},"previous_Year":{"grocery":40.02,"oac":0.0,"abc":40.74,"baby_care":0.0,"utensils":4.06}}
```

which is implemented through a model class

but when i am getting 403 status code response will be {"host":"xyz","message":"Forbidden","status":"token expired","timestamp":"2021-01-19T03:15:44.683"}
which cause my ui crash and error the method was called on null Receiver: null as it doesn't find the key values of model class
How can i handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the status code and pass the result accordingly

example:

```
if (result.statusCode==200){
//parse result to success object
}else if (result.statusCode==403){
//parse result to error object
}
```